# input element (generated by vuetify) won't break lines for long text

Tags: html, css, vue.js, vuetify.js

Using vue/vuetify 1.5x I have the following HTML code generated by v-combovox:

```
<input aria-label="Item Family" type="text" autocomplete="off" role="combobox">
```

It looks something like this:
[image: long family name]

What I need is to break the line so it will show the full text.

Things I have tried the following in style tag:

1)adding : `word-wrap: break-word`.
2)adding a `max-width: 500px` (the desired max length of one line).
3)adding a set `width`.
4)changing the display to `flex` or various other options.

I also just played around with a different css properties to make sure that the styles were catching and they were, e.g. text color would change when I set `color: green`.

What am I missing here? How can I force the input to break lines for the long text?

Comment: Maybe you need "textarea"?  https://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_elem_textarea

Comment: I can't have a text area since I am not rendering the element. Although if I really need to maybe will need to figure out how to get vuetify to do that.

Comment: What vuetify component are you using? Explain, please, your requirements for the element. Do you need kind of drop-down textarea?

Comment: v-combobox, it's buried in there somewhere...